# inputting the rates and selecting items/products, the total will calculate all real-time

Tags: javascript, html

here's the situation, daily rates, weekly rates, monthly rates,... it has six(6) items/products, each of them has different pricing on days' rates, weeks' rates, or months' rates. When inputting the rates and selecting items/products, the total should calculate all real-time.

p.s even with a rates' unfilled, it should still calculate.

```
<form>
          <!-- ***** Duration Start ***** -->
        <div>
            <h3>Duration</h3>
            <fieldset>
              <input type="text" id="days" name="Day/s" pattern="\d*" placeholder="Days"/>
              <input type="text" id="weeks" name="Week/s" pattern="\d*" placeholder="Weeks"/>
              <input type="text" id="months" name="Month/s" pattern="\d*" placeholder="Months"/>
            </fieldset>
            </div>
          <!-- ***** Duration End ***** -->
          <!-- ***** Items Start ***** -->
          <div> 
          <h3>Rental Products</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <fieldset>
              <input type="radio" id="item_1" name="product" />
              <label><span>item_1</span></label>
            </fieldset>
          </div>
          <div>
            <fieldset>
              <input type="radio" id="item_2" name="product" />
                <label><span>item_2</span></label>
            </fieldset>
          </div>
          <div>
            <fieldset>
              <input type="radio" id="item_3" name="product" />
                <label><span>item_3</span></label>
            </fieldset>
          </div>
          <div>
            <fieldset>
              <input type="radio" id="item_4" name="product" />
                <label><span>item_4</span></label>
            </fieldset>
          </div>
          <div>
            <fieldset>
              <input type="radio" id="item_5" name="product" />
                <label><span>item_5</span></label>
            </fieldset>
          </div>
          <div>
            <fieldset>
              <input type="radio" id="item_6" name="product" />
                <label><span>item_6</span></label>
            </fieldset>
          </div>
          <!-- ***** Items End ***** -->
          <!-- ***** Total Start ***** -->
          <div>
            <h3>Total Cost</h3>
            <fieldset>
            <output id="cost"></output>
            </fieldset>
          </div>
          <!-- ***** Total End ***** -->
</form>
```

```
<script>
{
    let cost = document.getElementById('item_1');

cost.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const numDays = parseInt(document.getElementById('days').value);
    const numWeeks = parseInt(document.getElementById('weeks').value);
    const numMonths = parseInt(document.getElementById('months').value);
    const totalCost = document.getElementById('cost');

    const total = ((280*numDays)+(1400*numWeeks)+(3200*numMonths)).toFixed(2);
    totalCost.innerHTML = '$ ' + total;
})
}

{
    let cost = document.getElementById('item_2');

cost.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const numDays = parseInt(document.getElementById('days').value);
    const numWeeks = parseInt(document.getElementById('weeks').value);
    const numMonths = parseInt(document.getElementById('months').value);
    const totalCost = document.getElementById('cost');

    const total = ((180*numDays)+(1000*numWeeks)+(2400*numMonths)).toFixed(2);
    totalCost.innerHTML = '$ ' + total;
})
}

{
    let cost = document.getElementById('item_3');

cost.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const numDays = parseInt(document.getElementById('days').value);
    const numWeeks = parseInt(document.getElementById('weeks').value);
    const numMonths = parseInt(document.getElementById('months').value);
    const totalCost = document.getElementById('cost');

    const total = ((250*numDays)+(1200*numWeeks)+(2800*numMonths)).toFixed(2);
    totalCost.innerHTML = '$ ' + total;
})
}

{
    let cost = document.getElementById('item_4');

cost.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const numDays = parseInt(document.getElementById('days').value);
    const numWeeks = parseInt(document.getElementById('weeks').value);
    const numMonths = parseInt(document.getElementById('months').value);
    const totalCost = document.getElementById('cost');

    const total = ((350*numDays)+(1700*numWeeks)+(3800*numMonths)).toFixed(2);
    totalCost.innerHTML = '$ ' + total;
})
}

{
    let cost = document.getElementById('item_5');

cost.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const numDays = parseInt(document.getElementById('days').value);
    const numWeeks = parseInt(document.getElementById('weeks').value);
    const numMonths = parseInt(document.getElementById('months').value);
    const totalCost = document.getElementById('cost');

    const total = ((200*numDays)+(900*numWeeks)+(1900*numMonths)).toFixed(2);
    totalCost.innerHTML = '$ ' + total;
})
}

{
    let cost = document.getElementById('item_6');

cost.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const numDays = parseInt(document.getElementById('days').value);
    const numWeeks = parseInt(document.getElementById('weeks').value);
    const numMonths = parseInt(document.getElementById('months').value);
    const totalCost = document.getElementById('cost');

    const total = ((150*numDays)+(600*numWeeks)+(1700*numMonths)).toFixed(2);
    totalCost.innerHTML = '$ ' + total;
})
}

</script>
```

this works on 'Click' but not on real-time once i click the item first before inputting duration, it wont calculate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following snippet shows how you can calculate the total cost at any time: after a change in the duration or after picking a different item.

As you can see I avoided a lot of code repetition by putting the rates as an array for each product into the object `rates`.

```js
const rates={
 item_1:[280,1400,3200],
 item_2:[180,1000,2400],
 item_3:[250,1200,2800],
 item_4:[350,1700,3800],
 item_5:[200, 900,1900],
 item_6:[150, 600,1700]};
const D=[], cost=document.getElementById("cost");

document.getElementById("h3rental").insertAdjacentHTML("afterend",Object.keys(rates).map(item=>`<div>
    <fieldset>
      <label><input type="radio" id="${item}" name="product" />
      <span>${item}</span></label>
    </fieldset>
  </div>`).join("\n"));


document.querySelector("fieldset").querySelectorAll("input").forEach(e=>{D.push(e);e.addEventListener("input",calc)});
document.querySelectorAll("input[name=product]").forEach(e=>{e.addEventListener("click",calc)});

function calc(ev){
 const prod=document.querySelector("input[name=product]:checked"),
   r=prod?rates[prod.id]:[0,0,0];
 cost.textContent=r.reduce((a,c,i)=>a+c*(D[i].value??0),0).toFixed(2);
}
```

```html
<form>
      <!-- ***** Duration Start ***** -->
    <div>
        <h3>Duration</h3>
        <fieldset>
          <input type="text" id="days" name="Day/s" pattern="\d*" placeholder="Days"/>
          <input type="text" id="weeks" name="Week/s" pattern="\d*" placeholder="Weeks"/>
          <input type="text" id="months" name="Month/s" pattern="\d*" placeholder="Months"/>
        </fieldset>
        </div>
      <!-- ***** Duration End ***** -->
      <!-- ***** Items Start ***** -->
      <div id="h3rental"> 
      <h3>Rental Products</h3>
      </div>
      <!-- ***** Items End ***** -->
      <!-- ***** Total Start ***** -->
      <div>
        <h3>Total Cost</h3>
        <fieldset>
        <output id="cost"></output>
        </fieldset>
      </div>
      <!-- ***** Total End ***** -->
</form>
```

I also simplified your HTML a bit and generated the fields with the radio buttons dynamically from the `rates` object. The result is shorter and easier to maintain.

As a further change I would recommend to limit the range of the input fields for days and weeks to same small values (something like 0 to 4 or 5 for days and 0 to 2 for weeks, as all higher values would result in unnecessarily higher costs, as a whole week or a whole month would be cheaper).